# Referencing filtered result of piped items in template

Tags: templates, angular

In a custom dropdown UI component I am showing items used in an `*ngFor` loop using the typical `let item in items; let ix = index` The index is then used to provide moving around the list with arrow up/down keys. I keep track of the last highlighted item and behave accordingly.

Problem arises when I add a search input field that provides a search term value to a pipe which then filters out non-matching items, as in:

`let item in items | searchPipe: currentTerm; let ix = index`

That's when the indices become messed up against what user sees.
I was wondering if this could be achieved in template syntax at all to get the current array of piped items and have indices applied over them.

Or should I rather call the pipe programmatically and create a filtered copy of `items` for each term, as in:

`let item in pipedItems; let ix = index`

and

`this.pipedItems = SearchPipe.transform(items, currentTerm);`

Could the same be achieved with a custom structural directive, like `*pipedFor`? Would it have any advantage (apart from its re-usability) over the former approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the way to go

```
this.pipedItems = new SearchPipe().transform(items, currentTerm);
```

There is currently no way to get the piped result inside the template.
As far as I remember it was discussed a while ago if this should be added but I don't think anything happened yet.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Could `.transform` be made a static method to simplify syntax? (2) I started to read docs about `trackByFn` - it is said to address item insertions/omissions on the UI side - do you think this could be a solution too?

Comment: (1) Yes, you can use a static method, but then it's not a pipe anymore. That wouldn't hurt, but discussion will become difficult if you name something pipe that actually isn't one ;-). You can also just make a `filter` method in your component. (2) `trackByFn` is just for `ngFor` to use custom equality comparison, for example required if `items` is an array of primitives like `boolean`, `number`, or `string`. I don't think this will help in any way.

Comment: `get pipedItems(){
    return new SearchPipe().transform(this.items, this.currentTerm);
  }
`
seems to work as a charm!

Comment: I don't think that's a good approach. You should call ` return new SearchPipe().transform(this.items, this.currentTerm)` **only** when `this.items` or `this.currentTerm` was modified. If you use `pipedItems` in the view it will be called every time change detection runs and `*ngFor` will re-render the while list every time change detection runs and will bring the performance of your application to its knees. Instead call it only when changes were made and assign the result to a property and bind to this property instead.

Comment: You mean using `OnChanges` for that purpose?

Comment: Hard to tell. It depends where that changes come from. When you get the array from an `@Input()`, then changes to the array (add/remove) won't cause `ngOnChanges` to be called. It's only called when a different array is passed. You might need to use `ngDoCheck` and `IterablesDiffer` (like done in `NgFor` or `NgClass` (check the source for an example) to check for changes in arrays passed as input. It might be easier to use a service with an observable where you get active notification about changes.

Comment: As SO is yelling at our extended discussion, let me just thank you for this invaluable insight, a good lesson learned!

Comment: Let SO yell :D You're welcome. I guess further questions might be worth a new SO question anyway though.